# Http2 protocol in an nginx reverse proxy and docker container

Tags: nginx, docker, reverse-proxy

I have an ubuntu 14.04 reverse proxy nginx 1.9.10 in front of 2 docker linux containers. One of those containers has an nginx server (1.9.10 too) which serves just static pages.

Since I knew that 'http2' protocol was available starting from nginx 1.9.5, I would like to use it in my infrastructure. But my question would be, should I have to enable the 'http2' protocol in my reverse proxy as well as in the nginx docker container? Or just in one of them?